# Capture clicks with parent form from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a parent page with an iframe in it. Inside the iframe is a single  tag. On the parent page, can I fire an event when that  tag is pressed? I know that if I place the javascript that captures the event inside the iframe then it will work, but for my project I need to have the parent page capture it.
This is my code so far.
Parent Code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var $MyFrame= $("#myiframe");
 $MyFrame.on("click", "a", function (e) {
         alert("hello");
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myiframe" height="3500" width="950" src="Iframe page" frameborder="0" style="display: block; margin: 10px auto;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my page in the iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $MyFrame = $("#myiframe");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');
    frameBody.find('a').click(function () {
        // here is the iframe a click callback
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this could help you with `.contents()` if frame source is at same origin:

```
 var $MyFrame= $("#myiframe");
 $MyFrame.contents().find('a').on("click", function (e) {
     alert("hello");
 });
```

and i noticed that you have assigned an `id` and you are referencing that frame with `class`.

Answer (score 0):

your `myiframe` is `id` and not `class`.. use id selector `#`

try this

```
var $MyFrame= $("#myiframe");
$MyFrame.on("click", "a", function (e) {
     alert("hello");
});
```